# Getting NTFS permissions of all shared folders on the local machine

Tags: performance, excel, file-system, windows, powershell

How can I improve the speed of the script?

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

$wSheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
$wSheet.Cells.item(1, 1) = "Folder Path:"
$wSheet.Cells.Item(1, 2) = "Users/Groups:"
$wSheet.Cells.Item(1, 3) = "Permissions:"
$wSheet.Cells.Item(1, 4) = "Permissions Inherited:"

$WorkBook = $wSheet.UsedRange
$WorkBook.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
$WorkBook.Font.ColorIndex = 11
$WorkBook.Font.Bold = $True

 ####Change the path to the folder or share you want NTFS perms on####
 $dirToAudit = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\inetpub" -recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }

 $intRow = 1
 foreach ($dir in $dirToAudit)
 {
     $colACL = Get-Acl -Path $dir.FullName

foreach ($acl in $colACL)
 {
    $intRow++
    $wSheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $dir.FullName

    foreach ($accessRight in $acl.Access)
    {
        $wSheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = "$($AccessRight.IdentityReference)"
        $wSheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 3) = "$($AccessRight.FileSystemRights)"
        $wSheet.Cells.Item($intRow, 4) = $acl.AreAccessRulesProtected
        $intRow++
    }
}

}
 $WorkBook.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

Comment: @Mast sorry my fault.  I have edited my question again thanks

Comment: Please edit the body of the question again - give a description of what it does rather than what you want. If it works, say it works and it does x and you want to know how to improve it. Rather than it looking like it does x but I want to do y.

Comment: Better, close vote retracted.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to improve the speed of the script is to drop the usage of Excel as a COM-object altogether. It is considered bad practice. And it is not possible on servers where Excel is not installed.

It's better to use a library like [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/documentation) (.NET port from Apache POI (java)).

I used this (old) [example](https://github.com/SQLServer/SampleCode/blob/master/Powershell/excel.ps1) as a base and adapted it to roughly match your code.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Release\Net40\NPOI.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Release\Net40\NPOI.OOXML.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Release\Net40\NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Release\Net40\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll")

$wb = New-Object NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook;
$ws = $wb.CreateSheet("output");
$ws.CreateRow(0)| out-null;

$dirToAudit = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\IEUser" -recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }

$intRow = 1

foreach ($dir in $dirToAudit)
{
    $colACL = Get-Acl -Path $dir.FullName

    foreach ($acl in $colACL)
    {
        $fileNameRow = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
        $fileNameRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue($dir.FullName)
        $intRow++

        foreach ($accessRight in $acl.Access)
        {
            $values = $ws.CreateRow($intRow)
            $values.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.IdentityReference).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue($($AccessRight.FileSystemRights).ToString())
            $values.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue($($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected).ToString())
            $intRow++
        }
    }

}
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream("C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\test.xlsx",[System.IO.FileMode]'Create',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Write')
$wb.Write($fs);
$fs.Close()
```

There is also another library for this kind of stuff: [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

And someone else made some nice [powershell functions](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) for it.

Comment: thanks guy just curious I want to test the speed of script via measure command. how can I do that?

Comment: `measure-command { <insert command/script block here> }`

Comment: OK Lastly I have got very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183345/how-to-read-ntfs-permissions-in-a-list-of-shares-from-a-text-file/39185426#39185426 I have updated my code but no luck. Could you please help me?

Comment: how can I add column header such as Folder Path , Users/Groups , Permissions , Permissions Inherited ?

Comment: I haven't tried out every possible function. But the easiest is to just create a row and fill it with the values you want. `$rowHeaders = $ws.CreateRow($row)` and put the next in a loop with your headerNames: `$rowHeaders.CreateCell($column).SetCellValue($headerName)`

Comment: Okay man like you said I've update my code its works very well. As you know Excel has got 1048574 rows.  How can I export more than  one million rows below my code ? if max rows is reached then how can I continue over new worksheet in  Loop ?  how to adapted it?

Comment: How useful is your excel if you're gonna have multiple worksheets with 10 million rows. Is anyone ever really gonna read it, or search for 'something' wrong? Wouldn't it be better to filter your initial query with the directories which permissions are not correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real need for Excel here at all actually. Any reason you could not just use a CSV that can be opened in Excel? `Export-CSV` and using more of the pipeline would most certainly be faster here.

```
$path = 'rootpath'
$exportPath = 'Path to export'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.psIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
    # Process each folder
    $singleFolder = $_
    $aclSet = $singleFolder | Get-Acl
    $aclset.Access | ForEach-Object{
        # Build a custom object, using a hashtable, for each access control set
        $props = @{
            "Folder Path" = $singleFolder.FullName
            "Users/Groups" = $_.IdentityReference
            Permissions = $_.FileSystemRights
            "Permissions Inherited" = $aclset.AreAccessRulesProtected
        }

        # Create and send the object down the pipeline
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
    }

# Ensure that the properties appear in the desired order. Issue with PowerShell 2.0
} | Select-Object "Folder Path", "Users/Groups", Permissions, "Permissions Inherited" |
    Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $exportPath
```

### Other thoughts

- `psIsContainer` is itself a boolean so you don't *need* to test it being true. PowerShell will do that all on its own.
- There is no error handling in your or my script snippet. If you don't have the right to read the folders, export the data and etc. the script would fail.